# Update Item Action error in Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, flow, power-automate, threshold

I have a SharePoint online list with approval mechanism set through Power Automate.

Now While executing the "Update Item" action I am getting below error:

> The query cannot be completed because the number of lookup columns it contains exceeds the lookup column threshold.

Within the update item action I am trying to update few fields and the list does not have any lookup column in it.

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Columns of type "Person and Group" are also treated as lookup columns, so if you have multiple columns like that, that could cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Lookup columns are:

1. Lookup
2. Managed metadata (single and multi-value)
3. People and group (single and multi-value)
4. Workflow status
5. Created by (people and group)
6. Modified by (people and group)

As a workaround, when using an action to collect data from a SharePoint list you can limit the gathered columns by **selecting a view with the required columns (less than 12 lookup columns) in the action.**

[image]

More information for your reference:

http://www.benprins.net/2019/01/15/flow-working-around-the-lookup-column-threshold/